# EventTrigger component only works with UI system?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I'm new to Unity and using 4.6 version.

I have a prefab which is just a sprite. And I instantiate three of them.

I want to receive touch and mouse events from those instances.

So, I added EventTrigger component to them from c# script, and added ClickEvent.

And I also added IPointerClickHandler and implement of it.

But it never gets any event. What am I missing?

Is TriggerSystem only works with UI system? Because I did not add any UI Pannel or UICanvas or etc. ( instead I added an empty object and added TriggerSystem component to it )

If this is not a good way to do, please give me a direction to start.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Thank you guys. It never worked with EventSystem for me. Maybe it only works on touch devices. So I added BoxCollider2D and used Input class. And it works anyway. Maybe I should check performance.

Comment: You need 2D Collider attached to that 2D Object/Sprite. http://stackoverflow.com/a/37456107/7444831

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below is for Mobile devices.

If you want to do in game controls without UI you can use `Input`

[This](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Input.GetTouch.html) is Unity document.

It pointed `TouchPhase` and all of touch phases can find [here](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/TouchPhase.html).

Unity document has good example codes i think you should check it.

Answer (score 0):

For GUI system to work there should also be an EventSystem object in your scene.

You can do it the easy way too, from the editor add a collider2d to the the sprite.

Write this to an script attach it the the gameObject.

```
void OnMouseDown() {
    // do something
}
```

Unity also convert mouse event to touch events on touch systems so you may not need to worry about simple touch events.